# Error during automated software install using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

After searching I am not able to find a good response:

I am trying to automate company software using pywinauto. I try to use `app.print_control_identifiers()` wherever possible. And it has been a God send! Thanks to folks on Youtube and Vasily's posts. See code below.

During the install, it wants to install a MS VC++ redistributable and I can handle that.

The next issue is telling me that the version of Adobe Flash Player (I know right?) is incompatible. I have used Inspect to ID the OK button I need to click to move on. Here is the code (cleaned up for public consumption):

```py
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time

app = Application(backend="uia").start("C:\\Users\\me\\program.exe")
time.sleep(5)
#This addresses the need to install Microsoft C++ Redistributable
dlg = app['program - InstallShield Wizard']
dlg.Install.click()
time.sleep(5)

#This is to get past an install failure and to move on
dlg.Yes.click()
time.sleep(10)

#This is a dialog box saying that some component is incompatible and this is where I am stuck
# And the window title now just says 'program' vs. 'program - InstallShield Wizard'
new_dlg = app['program']
new_dlg.OK.click()
```

Here is the failure info:

```
C:\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/myProject/pywinauto_install.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 258, in __resolve_control
    criteria)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/myProject/pywinauto_install.py", line 23, in <module>
    new_dlg.OK.click()

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 379, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 261, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 203, in __get_ctrl
    dialog = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**criteria[0]))

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)

pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'best_match': 'program', 'backend': 'uia', 'process': 22184}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am creating new_dlg based on an SO post I saw, so if this is wrong, please slap my hand. I am not a trained developer.
Thanks

Comment: Could you also add a link to the SO post your new_dlg is based on?

Comment: The new_dlg is based on the name of the program, which I had to modify as this is internal software and I can't share the actual name. So when I start the installation, I get the name "program - InstallShield" for the VC++ redistributable for the title. Then the title drops the "- InstallShield" to just be "program" HTH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check texts of the top level dialog windows print this:

```
print([w.window_text() for w in app.windows()])
```

Then just copy the correct one to your code as a dict key instead of `app['program']`. More flexible way looks so:

```
new_dlg = app.window(title_re="Program - .*")
```

Comment: The print command returns [] so pywinauto is not finding anything. I tried the new_dlg and that failed same as before. I am sure it has to do with my company's install process of kicking off a setup.exe then extracting the msi to a new folder every time. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Maybe the installer spawns a child process which is not automatically tracked by pywinauto (for now). You have to do `child_app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="exact title", timeout=10)` to make sure the dialog is appeared in 10 sec maximum. Then do `new_dlg = child_app.window(title="exact title")` and proceed further. Also `title_re` param may be helpful instead.

Comment: That did it! I was able to click the OK button and move on. And now I need to ask about how to handle buttons with a > in the title. I can open a new SO question so we can track it separately?

Comment: No need to open a new question! I found that if I used title="Next >" I can click on just about anything!